Changing Next.js route with vanilla Javascript
I need to change the route of a Next.js application using vanilla Javascript. I want this code to work on Chrome Dev Tools so I cannot change the route dynamically with Next.js so I have to achieve this with plain Javascript.
I was able to do this on Vue.js applications like this:
window.history.pushState({}, '', '/directory');
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('popstate'));

Unfortunately popstates are not working on Next applications. I need a wayaround to that, I'm sure the code should resemble the Vue.js example, but I cannot figure that out.

To change routes from outside the Next.js context, there is no built-in or supported method to do so without a page reload, other than using the router methods provided by Next.js. Therefore, the only solution, not elegant and lacking seamless client-side transitions that you would normally expect, is:
window.history.pushState({}, '', '/directory');
window.location.reload();

